# Regex lookahead/lookbehind comments

Tags: ruby, regex, negative-lookbehind, rubular

I have a snippet from a config file that I need to be able to match the specified string quote contents, but only when they're not commented out, here's my current regex:

```
(?<!=#)test\.this\.regex\s+\"(.*?)\"
```

I feel like this should work? I read it like this:

`(?<!=#)` lookbehind to make sure it's not preceded by a `#`

`test\.this\.regex\s+\"(.*?)\"` matches `test.this.regex "sup1"`

Here is the config snippet

```
    test.this.regex "sup1" hi |sup1| # test.this.regex "sup3" hi |sup3|
# test.this.regex "sup2" do |sup2|
    test.this.regex "sup2" do |sup2|
```

But my regex matches all 4 times:

```
Match 1
1.  sup1
Match 2
1.  sup3
Match 3
1.  sup2
Match 4
1.  sup2
```

Comment: Which language/tool are you using for this?

Comment: There seems to be a space after `#` that you haven't accounted for in your regex.

Comment: The syntax of a negative lookbehind is `(?<!...)`, not `(?<!=...)`

Comment: @anubhava I'm using this http://rubular.com/ since it supports lookaheads/lookbehinds

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte doesn't make a difference

Comment: It's because you have forgotten the space.

Comment: @DarkCthulhu that is definitely the cause, but how do I check for anything between the `#` and the string I want to match? I tried .* after `#`, and before `test`, neither works

Comment: @bruchowski: it's always good to tag with what language. Tagged [tag:ruby], [tag:rubular], [tag:negative-lookbehind]. Retag as wished.

Comment: @smci thanks, will do in the future

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this PCRE regex:

```
/(?># *(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|(?:^|\s))test\.this\.regex\s+\"[^"]*\"/
```

#### [Working Demo](http://regex101.com/r/fT5jI4)

- `(*FAIL)` behaves like a failing negative assertion and is a synonym for `(?!)`
- `(*SKIP)` defines a point beyond which the regex engine is not allowed to backtrack when the subpattern fails later
- `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` together provide a nice alternative of restriction that you cannot have a variable length lookbehinf in above regex.

---

**UPDATE:** Not sure whether ruby supports `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` so giving this alternative version:

```
(?:# *test\.this\.regex\s+\"[^"]*\"|\b(test\.this\.regex\s+\"[^"]*\"))
```

And look for non-empty matched group #1.

[Working Demo 2](http://rubular.com/r/eftetCbKqL)

Comment: This breaks if there is more than one space after the # though

Comment: Clarify this in your question and that's precisely the reason why I asked which language you use?

Comment: I thought I did in the first sentence, sorry if you missed that; I also noted I was using Ruby's regex implementation. It should match if there is anything between the `#` and `test.this.regex`, since that means it's a comment and I want to disregard that match

Comment: See updated answer. Your question needs to be tagged with language/tool in addition to regex actually.

Comment: I had this before, `(#)?.*test\.this\.regex\s+\"(.*)\"` but I was hoping I could match just the strings I wanted with only one capture group

Comment: `(#)?.*test\.this\.regex\s+\"(.*)\"` won't help since it will match both strings and you **cannot have** dynamic length in lookbehind.

Comment: `cannot have dynamic length in lookbehind` that's the missing piece, thanks, I didn't know that

Comment: I believe other than .NET no other language supports dynamic length `lookbehinds`.

Answer (score 0):

If you question is embodied in the first sentence (and not specifically about lookarounds) why don't you just use [String#split](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-split) with your regex less the lookbehind?

```
def doit(str)
  r = /test\.this\.regex\s+\"(.*?)\"/
  str.split('#').first[r,1]
end

doit('test.this.regex "sup1" hi |sup1| # test.this.regex "sup3" hi |sup3|')
  #=> "sup1"
doit('# test.this.regex "sup2" do |sup2|')
  #=> nil
doit('test.this.regex "sup2" do |sup2|')
  #=> "sup2"
```